# How to combine the output from an object and an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have a db query that returns a value to the `$result` variable that looks like this:

```
    Collection {#710 ▼
  #items: array:16 [▼
    0 => {#717 ▼
      +"utest_step_id": 18
      +"value": "1"
      +"count": 26
    }
    1 => {#716 ▼
      +"utest_step_id": 18
      +"value": "2"
      +"count": 23
    }
    2 => {#709 ▶}
    3 => {#711 ▶}
    4 => {#713 ▶}
    5 => {#714 ▶}
    6 => {#715 ▶}
    7 => {#718 ▶}
    8 => {#719 ▶}
    9 => {#720 ▶}
    10 => {#721 ▶}
    11 => {#722 ▶}
    12 => {#723 ▶}
    13 => {#724 ▶}
    14 => {#725 ▶}
    15 => {#726 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I have an array called `$steps` that I need to combine with the data that looks like this:

```
[▼
  0 => {#676 ▼
    +"id": 18
    +"step": 1
    +"type": "select many image"
    +"featured": false
    +"data": {#664 ▼
      +"description": "Ut quaerat ut sed molestiae."
      +"randomize": 0
      +"options": array:4 [▼
        0 => {#671 ▼
          +"position": 1
          +"image_url": "http://lorempixel.com/455/255/?67678"
          +"caption": "Prof."
          +"image_source": "http://lorempixel.com/455/255/?67678"
        }
        1 => {#668 ▼
          +"position": 2
          +"image_url": "http://lorempixel.com/455/255/?23876"
          +"caption": "Ms."
          +"image_source": "http://lorempixel.com/455/255/?23876"
        }
        2 => {#670 ▼
          +"position": 3
          +"image_url": "http://lorempixel.com/455/255/?45833"
          +"caption": "Prof."
          +"image_source": "http://lorempixel.com/455/255/?45833"
        }
        3 => {#677 ▼
          +"position": 4
          +"image_url": "http://lorempixel.com/455/255/?83800"
          +"caption": "Dr."
          +"image_source": "http://lorempixel.com/455/255/?83800"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  1 => {#690 ▶}
  2 => {#697 ▶}
  3 => {#704 ▶}
  4 => {#706 ▶}
]
```

I am trying to insert the value from `count` in `$results` into the `$steps->data->options` array.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $comparison_field = 'position';

    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($steps); $i++) {
        if ($result->utest_step_id == $steps[$i]->id) {
            foreach ($steps[$i]->data->options as $option) {
                $option->count = 0;
                $option->count = $result->count;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The problem is I am ending up with the count from the last `$result->utest_step_id` in each `count` item in the `$option`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a for loop iterating over all of the elements in `$steps` for each entry in `$results`. This results in everything in `$steps` being overwritten for each element in `$results`. If these arrays are supposed to line up, grab an `$id` from the `$results` loop:

```
foreach ($results AS $id=>$result)
```

and use that instead of `$i` in a for loop.